# Python 3.6 - getting error 'an integer is required (got type str)' while converting some strings to time

Tags: python, string, datetime

I wrote a function that takes in a row that has some raw numeric data in one of the columns and converts it to appropriate minutes (its a csv file). All the columns have been kept as strings if at all I need to wrangle with them since strings makes it easier. However, when converting some data into time format (again in strings), I get the error described in the title. My functions looks like the following:

```
def duration_in_mins(row, city):
    duration = [] # Make an empty list
    form = '%M.%S'

    if city == 'X':
       city_file = open('X.csv')
       city_csv = csv.reader(city_file)

       for row in city_csv:
           duration.append(row[1]) # The column that contains the strings

           for i in duration:
               datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strftime(form, 'minutes') # Conversion
        else:
           return 'Error'
    return duration
```

The line `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strftime(form, 'minutes')` is where I'm getting the error according to traceback when I run `duration_in_mins()`. Is the traceback telling me to convert the string into numeric first and then to time? Can datetime not convert strings directly into time?

```
duration_in_mins(5, 'X)
line 39, in duration_in_mins
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strptime(form, 'minutes')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Show the error and trace.

Comment: `for row in city_csv:` this doesnt look right. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Appending the `duration` list to contain only a specific column`[1]` from the original csv file that has been read. Thats what its supposed to do...

Comment: `datetime.fromtimestamp()` expects a numeric argument. So yes, if `i` is a string, you'll need to convert it to an int or float explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is an incoherence between your code and the reported error:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strftime(form, 'minutes') # Conversion
```

and

```
line 39, in duration_in_mins
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i).strptime(form, 'minutes')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Please note `strptime` is different than `strftime`

Then, you should split the line with error to understand what function exactly caused the exception:

```
x = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i)
x.strftime(form, 'minutes') # Conversion
```

And you will probably see that the error comes from [`fromtimestamp(ts)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromtimestamp#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) which needs an integer timestamp argument instead of a str.

Convert this argument as int at some point and everything should be ok.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting nearer. Will report back morning!

Answer (score 2):

As you say, `datetime.fromtimestamp()` requires a number but you are giving it a string. Python has a philosophy "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess" so it will throw an exception if you give a function an object of the wrong type.

Other problems with the code:

- The `strftime()` method will only take one argument but you're
  passing it a second one.
- Also, did you mean to nest those loops? Every time you append another
  value to `duration` you convert all of the values in the list to times, and
  then if the conversion did work you are just throwing away the result
  of the conversion and not saving it anywhere.