# Pandas, TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter my Column New_Date .

```
0    2019-11-20
1    2019-11-18
2    2019-11-16
3    2019-11-13
4    2019-11-11
5    2019-11-10
6    2019-11-08
7    2019-11-06
8    2019-11-02
9    2019-11-01
10   2019-10-30
11   2019-10-28
12   2019-10-26
13   2019-10-01
14          NaT
15          NaT
16   2019-10-18
17   2019-10-13
18   2019-10-10
19   2019-10-08
20          NaT
21          NaT


filterdate = datetime.date(input())
d1 = d1[(d1['New_Date'] > '{filterdate}') & (d1['New_Date'] != 'NaT')]
```

I input my date in this format "2019-11-11"

and I get this `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an `f` missing before `'{filterdate}'`, as in `f'{filterdate}'`?

Comment: You don't need the curly brackets. Simply `df[(df["New_Date"]>filterdate)&df["New_Date"].notnull()]` should do (assuming your date column is datetime dtype).

Comment: Should work just fine without wrapping the input()

Comment: `input()` takes whatever string you type in (**do not surround it with quotes, it's already a string**), then `datetime.date(...)` converts it.

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Python 3.6 - getting error 'an integer is required (got type str)' while converting some strings to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872522/python-3-6-getting-error-an-integer-is-required-got-type-str-while-convert)

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.6 - getting error 'an integer is required (got type str)' while converting some strings to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872522/python-3-6-getting-error-an-integer-is-required-got-type-str-while-convert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is with this line:

`filterdate = datetime.date(input())`

The datetime.date() function is actually not able to parse the date correctly and is giving you this TypeError.

#### Method 1

What you can try is this:

`date = str(input())
year, month, day = map(int, date.split('-'))
filterdate = datetime.date(year, month, day)`

and then you can compare it like this:

`d1 = d1[(d1['New_Date'] > filterdate) & (d1['New_Date'] != 'NaT')]`

#### Method 2

The other way to get around this problem is by using the datetime.date.fromisoformat() function.

`filterdate = datetime.date.fromisoformat(input())`

and then,

`d1 = d1[(d1['New_Date'] > filterdate) & (d1['New_Date'] != 'NaT')]`

More details about datetime can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Hi Sarques, this works! however getting msg `FutureWarning: Comparing Series of datetimes with 'datetime.date'.  Currently, the
'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future pandas will
not coerce, and a TypeError will be raised. To retain the current
behavior, convert the 'datetime.date' to a datetime with
'pd.Timestamp'.`

Comment: Hey @excelguy I am glad that it worked, the warning is because we are trying to compare a pandas timestamp series with a `datetime.time` element, what you should do is take `filterdate` as a pandas timestamp element and then compare, and it will work fine. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding this correctly, you can try:

```
filterdate = input("Input Date in format ((Year-Month-Day): ")
d1[(d1['Date'] > filterdate) & (d1['Date'] != 'NaT')]
```

Inputing "2019-11-11" without the quotes (using data from another of your posts)

```
Input Date in format Year-Month-Day: 2019-11-10
#Out[2203]: 
#   Date        OPP    Result
#0  2019-11-16  @DAL   L110-102
#1  2019-11-13  @POR   W114-106
#2  2019-11-11  @LAC   L98-88
```

Comment: Hi oppression, the code runs fine, however still not filtering. The column is called 'New_Date' . Any ideas on why its not filtering?